# SQLite database, multithreading, Locks and account sync on android

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, locking

I'm trying to get a pattern that doesn't fail for a multithreaded access to my sqlite database. Also, what is driving me nuts is that I can't reproduce the issue.

I have an app which uses a DB, but also Android Accounts and Android sync to sync my app's data. My guess is that when the two happen a the same time, it crashes. I'm getting a lot of errors like:

```
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: error code 5: database is locked
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 778)
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/net.bicou.redmine/databases/redmine.db' to 'en_US'. \n Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)
```

Maybe not all of them are related to the same root cause, however I'm kind of lost.

What I have is:

- an abstract base class, `DbAdapter`, that is extended by subclasses which want to manage a single table
- a class that manages the SQLite database, called `DbManager`, which contains a `Lock`

Right now the users have a version of the `DbManager` that is not a singleton. I'm planning to make `DbManager` a singleton, so that all threads share the same object. This shouldn't be a problem, because as far as I have understood/seen, the background sync and app share the same process.

Here are the classes (only the relevant parts):

```
public abstract class DbAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    protected DbManager mDbManager;
    SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    public DbAdapter(final Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
    }

    public DbAdapter(final DbAdapter other) {
        mContext = other.mContext;
        mDb = other.mDb;
        mDbManager = other.mDbManager; // removed with singleton version
    }

    public synchronized DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        if (mDb != null) {
            return this;
        }

        mDbManager = new DbManager(mContext); // currently in production
        mDbManager = DbManager.instance(mContext); // currently investigating this singleton solution
        try {
            mDb = mDbManager.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            L.e("Unable to open DB, trying again in 1 second", e);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e1) {
                L.e("Could not wait 1 second " + e1);
            }
            mDb = mDbManager.getWritableDatabase();// This may crash
        }

        return this;
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        mDbManager.close();
        mDbManager = null;
        mDb = null;
    }
}
```

A class that needs to handle a database table will extend `DbAdapter`, and implement methods such as `select`, `insert`, `delete`, etc.

Here's the DB manager:

```
public class DbManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_FILE = "db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 15;
    Context mContext;
    Lock mLock = new ReentrantLock();

    // Currently in prod
    public DbManager(final Context context) {
        super(context, DB_FILE, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    // singleton version will make this constructor private and add:
    private static DbManager mInstance;
    public static synchronized DbManager instance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DbManager(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        mLock.lock();
        return super.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
        mLock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
        // ...
    }

    private void createTables(final SQLiteDatabase db, final String[] statements) {
        for (final String sql : statements) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(sql);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                L.e("Unable to create table: " + sql, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

OK, now, the questions.

1. Is my lock properly implemented? I'm really new to this, I don't know if the `ReentrantLock` is a good choice, and if I'm locking/unlocking at the right moment
2. Are my `synchronized` method properly implemented? I mean, I have placed the `synchronized` keyword around methods that I don't want interrupted by concurrent threads. Is this right? Can you advice on my `synchronized` use?
3. How can I reproduce the issue? I have created a test that uses 3 threads that make concurrent read/write access to the DB, and use some `Thread.sleep` to ensure that the db open/close from each thread overlap, but it doesn't crash. This is really bugging me, I don't think there is a lot of people that have the issue, so I don't know how to reproduce.
4. Is my `DbAdapter` + `DbManager` technical choice a good idea? Is there a better pattern?
5. Is it a good idea to make `DbManager` a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple threads accessing, it is advisable to use the singleton pattern.

Such a way, successive calls to the same database will be seamlessly serialised.

However, it's not impossible to have some `NullPointerException`s on inserts. So, to expand your "`Thread.sleep`" logic, you could use this code:

```
@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return super.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteDatabaseLockedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```